# C# XmlSerializer: Create xmlns attribute on a nested object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

The API I want to use requires me so set the `xmlns`-attribute on a nested element, like this:

```
<root>
   <mainelement>
   </mainelement>
   <mainelement>
      <subelement xmlns="http://example.com/xml" otherAttr="value">
      </subelement>
   </mainelement>    
</root>
```

The class of `subelement` is defined like this:

```
public class subelement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string otherAttr { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string xmlns { get; set; } = "http://example.com/xml";
}
```

However, when I try to serialize the root object with XmlSerializer the `xmlns`-attribute is always missing. Otherwise it's working fine. When I rename this attribute it created, so I guess it has something to do with `xmlns` as reserved keyword.

Also I am not able to use the standard way of setting namespaces as third parameter of the `Serialize` method because I just want this attribute to be on the `subelement` object.

Is there a way to accomplish this without manually editing the file after serialization?

Comment: This should be solved by simply setting the [Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `subelement`s [XmlElementAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the correct namespace on the `subelement` property in `mainelement`.

```
public class mainelement
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://example.com/xml")]
    public subelement subelement { get; set; }
}

public class subelement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string otherAttr { get; set; }    
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlRzOW) for a working demo.